# SQL Query INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem about transferring values from one table to another.

Below are my tables and columns:

TABLE: **a_logs**

```
a_log_id - status - status_date - description

1 - null - null - hello world
```

TABLE: **a_logs_history**

```
a_hist_id - a_log_id - status - status_date - description

1 - 1 - 5 - 2013-10-19 - hello world
2 - 1 - 7 - 2013-10-25 - hello world
```

I want to insert recent status w/c is 7 and recent status_date w/c is 2013-10-25 values from a_logs_history table to a_logs table.

I tried using INSERT INTO SELECT but I got an error.

Help me please? Thanks.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error did you get? Please don't just tease us - tell us **exactly and completely** what the error is that you've got! We can't see your screen or read your mind - you need to tell us in order to be able to help you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO a_logs VALUES (1,(SELECT status,status_date FROM a_logs_history WHERE  recent status = 7 ,  status_date = '2013-10-25'),'XXX')
```

In the above example i represented status date as string, it may change as you declared..

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

We can copy only the columns we want to into another, existing table:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```